# Compare multiple objects and add missing keys to every object with no value

Tags: javascript

I'm creating a product comparison component in Vue.js.
I have a variable number of objects, between 2 and 4.
Every object has the same structure. This is the simplified structure for **Object A**

```
[{
 id:"123", 
 name: "Design",
 features: {
   data: [{
     id: "2222",
     name: "Screen"
     value: "OLED"
     },
     { id: "3333",
     name: "Material"
     value: "Metal"
     }],
 },
 {
 id:"126", 
 name: "Size and Weight",
 features: {
   data: [{
     id: "444",
     name: "Size"
     value: "34mm"
     },
     { id: "555",
     name: "Weight"
     value: "900gr"
     }],
 }
 ]
```

Basically my object is an array of groups, and in every group I have the product features.
This is a sample of my **Object B**

```
[{
 id:"123", 
 name: "Design",
 features: {
   data: [{
     id: "2222",
     name: "Screen"
     value: "OLED"
     },
     { id: "4444",
     name: "Color"
     value: "Red"
     }],
 },
 {
 id:"245", 
 name: "Connectivity",
 features: {
   data: [{
     id: "786",
     name: "5G"
     value: "Yes"
     }],
 }
 ]
```

Now the problem: not every product has the same groups with the same features. Maybe the product "A" has 6 groups while the product "B" has only 5 groups, maybe in the first group of the product "A" I have 3 features while in the same group (design... for example) of the product B I have 4 features.

I know that I have the Spread Operator

```
const compare = {...firstObject, ...secondObject};
```

But with the spread operator I have a merged object...

I don't have to merge the objects, I have to keep the products in an array to draw my comparison table.
But I need to fill for every object the missing key with no value. So this should be my A object after the "merge"

```
 [{
 id:"123", 
 name: "Design",
 features: {
   data: [{
     id: "2222",
     name: "Screen"
     value: "OLED"
     },
     { id: "3333",
     name: "Material"
     value: "Metal"
     },
     { id: "4444",
     name: "Color"
     value: ""
     }],
 },
 {
 id:"126", 
 name: "Size and Weight",
 features: {
   data: [{
     id: "444",
     name: "Size"
     value: "34mm"
     },
     { id: "555",
     name: "Weight"
     value: "900gr"
     }],
 },
  {
 id:"245", 
 name: "Connectivity",
 features: {
   data: [{
     id: "786",
     name: "5G"
     value: ""
     }],
 }
 ]
```

So, for example, If object B has a feature called "5G Connection" I need to add this feature with no value in object A, C and D. Every feature and every group has an ID, [here a sample json with the real structure](https://jsoneditoronline.org/#left=cloud.2492759378d0451e9162e513e3b26f0a)

Any hint?

Comment: You are right... I edit the title

Comment: Your json is invalid; try copy-pasting into validator: https://duckduckgo.com/?q=json+validator

Comment: without considering any fancy shortcut, the naive way to do this is to iterate through object B (or array that contains a lot of objects) and then get a set that include all features, then iterate through the array you want to modify and add missing features  by checking the key existence.

Comment: @Yunhai I have in my backend the entire structure, so all the possible groups of feature and for every group all the features...

Comment: Or if  `Spread Operator then merge ` meet your satisfaction , why don't you simply merge and then remove whatever objects that has same `id` from object B. In this case, you just need a new loop to remove unwanted items. Sometimes it's hard to find that shortcut even though we all know it exists somewhere so just try some fundamentals.